# Taylor series expansion $ (1-\varepsilon)^{-(\kappa-1)/\kappa}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Can please someone help with finding the Taylor series expansion to this exponential? I am only looking for the first two terms, thanks!

$(1-\varepsilon)^{-(\kappa-1)/\kappa}$

Comment: What's the $\&$ symbol? And what's the variable?

Comment: @Andrei sorry there is no &, I just edited it, $\kappa$ is just a constant in this case.

Comment: if $\kappa$ is a constant, then $\exp(-(\kappa-1)/\kappa)$ is also a constant

Comment: @Andrei exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a constant $C$ and small $\varepsilon$, $$(1-\varepsilon)^C\approx 1-C\varepsilon+\frac {C(C-1)}2\varepsilon^2+...$$
Just plug in $$C=-\frac{\kappa-1}\kappa$$

Comment: @Thanks alot! Do you have a reference how you came across this answer?

Comment: Take the derivatives: $f(x)=(1+x)^p$. Then $f'(x)=p(1+x)^{p-1}$ and $f''(x)=p(p-1)(1+x)^{p-2}$

Comment: Thank you :) It worked.